# C# Graphics Object is currently in use elsewhere

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, exception

I created a game based on a totorial to start learning, I am rendering my game with renderScreen(), when I moved my window on screen I have got this exception "Object is currently in use elsewhere". I know the reason of error but I could not fix it as I do not know how to do that.
What can I do ? Forgive me if question is stupid.

**engine.cs**

```
//MEMBERS
public static Graphics drawHandle;
private Thread renderThread;

public engine(Graphics g)
{
    drawHandle = g;
}
private object bufferLock = new object();

public void init()
{
    renderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(renderScreen));
    renderThread.Start();
}

public void stop()
{
    renderThread.Abort();
}

public static Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(Globals.CANVAS_WIDTH, Globals.CANVAS_HEIGHT);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, frame.Width, frame.Height);

private void renderScreen()
{
    int framesRendered = 0;
    long startTime = Environment.TickCount;
    Graphics frameGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(frame);
    Unit1 unit1 = new Unit1("test1");
    Unit1 unit2 = new Unit1("test2");unit2.x = 250; unit2.y = 100;

    Globals.GameUnitsList.Add(unit1); Globals.GameUnitsList.Add(unit2);

    while (true)
    {
        //BACKGROUND
        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkBlue),0,0, Globals.CANVAS_WIDTH, Globals.CANVAS_HEIGHT);

        //BOXES
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(unit1.x, unit1.y, 50, 50);

        unit1.rectangle = rect;

        unit1.fillColor = Brushes.LightBlue;
        unit1.hitPoints = 100;
        unit1.Health = 10;

        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(unit1.fillColor, unit1.rectangle);
        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(unit1.fillColor, unit1.rectangle);

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(unit2.x, unit2.y, 50, 50);
        unit2.rectangle = rect2;
        unit2.fillColor = Brushes.LightBlue;
        unit2.hitPoints = 100;
        unit2.Health = 50;

        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(unit2.fillColor, unit2.rectangle);
        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(unit2.fillColor, unit2.rectangle);

        //HEALTH BAR
        HealthBar hb = new HealthBar();
        hb.barColor = Brushes.YellowGreen;
        hb.damageColor = Brushes.Red;
        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(hb.damageColor, hb.Draw(unit1, unit1.x, unit1.y)[1]);
        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(hb.barColor, hb.Draw(unit1, unit1.x, unit1.y)[0]);
        HealthBar hb2 = new HealthBar();
        hb2.barColor = Brushes.YellowGreen;
        hb2.damageColor = Brushes.Red;
        frameGraphics.FillRectangle(hb2.damageColor, hb2.Draw(unit2, unit2.x, unit2.y)[1]);
            frameGraphics.FillRectangle(hb2.barColor, hb2.Draw(unit2, unit2.x, unit2.y)[0]);

        //UNIT NAMES
        frameGraphics.DrawString(unit1.unitName, new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Yellow, unit1.x + 50, unit1.y + 50);
        frameGraphics.DrawString(unit2.unitName, new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Yellow, unit2.x + 50, unit2.y + 50);

        drawHandle.DrawImage(frame, 0, 0);

        //BENCHMARKING
        if (Environment.TickCount >= startTime + 750)
        {
            framesRendered++;
        }

        if (Environment.TickCount>=startTime+1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Gomi-Invade Plan Game:"+framesRendered +"fps "+ Environment.TickCount);
            framesRendered = 0;
            startTime = Environment.TickCount;
        }
    }
}
```

**gamewindow.cs**

```
...
public static GameWindow gameW;
Game game = new Game();
...
//I have this code inside it but is this wrong ?        
private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = canvas.CreateGraphics();
    game.startGraphics(g);
}
...
```

**game.cs**

```
private engine Gengine;

public void startGraphics(Graphics g)
{
    Gengine = new GomiEngine(g);
    Gengine.init();
}

public void stopGame()
{
    Gengine.stop();
}
```

Comment: _Graphics g = canvas.CreateGraphics();_ This is wrong indeed. You have the valid Graphics object in the PainArgs: `e.Graphics`. Do note that you can pass it out for drawing but you shall not store or cache it for later use! Instead you need to trigger the Paint event whenever new data need to be drawn! Also you are mixing drawing onto a Control in the Paint event and drawing into aBitmap. This may well be right, but you need to understand what you are doing!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot render screen in your own thread, you need to call invalidate in invoke which will enqueue windows message to windows message loop which will be processed on main thread.

```
private void DoWorkInThread(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        lock(this)
        {
                //update member properties
        }

        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate void ()
            {
                //this.Invalidate(); //if you don't need to render every frame, invalidate is better then refresh
                this.Refresh();  //call refresh for immediate update
            });
    }    
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    lock(this)
    {
        //read your member which are modifies by the thread
    }
    //do rendering
    e.Graphics.Draw(...);
```

}